# Failing test case if store state update in UI

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, react-testing-library, redux-toolkit

I have setup a redux toolkit project for my learning and was going through a test cases, but going through multiple tutorial I got confused regarding how to write test case if a component includes useSelector, useDispatch.

Here is my React Component  (Counter.tsx)-

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { useAppSelector, useAppDispatch } from '../../app/hooks';
import {
  decrement,
  increment,
  incrementByAmount,
  incrementAsync,
  incrementIfOdd,
  selectCount,
} from './counterSlice';
import styles from './Counter.module.css';

export function Counter() {
  const count = useAppSelector(selectCount);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const [incrementAmount, setIncrementAmount] = useState('2');

  const incrementValue = Number(incrementAmount) || 0;

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles.row}>
        <button
          className={styles.button}
          aria-label="Decrement value"
          onClick={() => dispatch(decrement())}
        >
          -
        </button>
        <span className={styles.value}>{count}</span>
        <button
          className={styles.button}
          aria-label="Increment value"
          onClick={() => dispatch(increment())}
        >
          +
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.row}>
        <input
          className={styles.textbox}
          aria-label="Set increment amount"
          value={incrementAmount}
          onChange={(e) => setIncrementAmount(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button
          className={styles.button}
          onClick={() => dispatch(incrementByAmount(incrementValue))}
        >
          Add Amount
        </button>
        <button
          className={styles.asyncButton}
          onClick={() => dispatch(incrementAsync(incrementValue))}
        >
          Add Async
        </button>
        <button
          className={styles.button}
          onClick={() => dispatch(incrementIfOdd(incrementValue))}
        >
          Add If Odd
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is my Counter Slice -

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { RootState, AppThunk } from '../../app/store';
import { fetchCount } from './counterAPI';

export interface CounterState {
  value: number;
  status: 'idle' | 'loading' | 'failed';
}

const initialState: CounterState = {
  value: 5,
  status: 'idle',
};

// The function below is called a thunk and allows us to perform async logic. It
// can be dispatched like a regular action: `dispatch(incrementAsync(10))`. This
// will call the thunk with the `dispatch` function as the first argument. Async
// code can then be executed and other actions can be dispatched. Thunks are
// typically used to make async requests.
export const incrementAsync = createAsyncThunk(
  'counter/fetchCount',
  async (amount: number) => {
    const response = await fetchCount(amount);
    // The value we return becomes the `fulfilled` action payload
    return response.data;
  }
);

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState,
  // The `reducers` field lets us define reducers and generate associated actions
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => {
      // Redux Toolkit allows us to write "mutating" logic in reducers. It
      // doesn't actually mutate the state because it uses the Immer library,
      // which detects changes to a "draft state" and produces a brand new
      // immutable state based off those changes
      state.value += 1;
    },
    decrement: (state) => {
      state.value -= 1;
    },
    // Use the PayloadAction type to declare the contents of `action.payload`
    incrementByAmount: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.value += action.payload;
    },
  },
  // The `extraReducers` field lets the slice handle actions defined elsewhere,
  // including actions generated by createAsyncThunk or in other slices.
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(incrementAsync.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = 'loading';
      })
      .addCase(incrementAsync.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'idle';
        state.value += action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(incrementAsync.rejected, (state) => {
        state.status = 'failed';
      });
  },
});

export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } = counterSlice.actions;

// The function below is called a selector and allows us to select a value from
// the state. Selectors can also be defined inline where they're used instead of
// in the slice file. For example: `useSelector((state: RootState) => state.counter.value)`
export const selectCount = (state: RootState) => state.counter.value;

// We can also write thunks by hand, which may contain both sync and async logic.
// Here's an example of conditionally dispatching actions based on current state.
export const incrementIfOdd =
  (amount: number): AppThunk =>
  (dispatch, getState) => {
    const currentValue = selectCount(getState());
    if (currentValue % 2 === 1) {
      dispatch(incrementByAmount(amount));
    }
  };

export default counterSlice.reducer;
```

And here is my Counter spec file-

```
import React from 'react';
import {render, screen} from '@testing-library/react'
import { Counter } from './Counter';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from '../../app/store';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

describe('Counter should render', () => {
  test('should', () => {
   render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Counter />
    </Provider>

   );
  });
  test('increment no on add click', () => {

     render(
     <Provider store={store}>
       <Counter />
     </Provider>
 
    );
    const incrementBtn = screen.getByLabelText('Increment value');
    act(()=> incrementBtn.click())
    expect(store.getState().counter.value).toBe(6);
   });
})
```

Here in my spec file I am wrapping my code by Provider with actual store, and it getting passed also. But in UI if I change my store state, My test case starts to fail as I have equality to counter value as 6.
So is this normal ?

As I saw many pages, people are mocking useSelector/ useDispatch with Jest.fn().

So should we do mocking for useSelector/useDispatch ?`

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you should not mock `useSelector`/`useDispatch`, it will probably break their functions. This will cause your test code to pass based on the wrong implementation.
2. The results of each test case are predictable.
3. Test cases should ideally be independent of each other. You can create a redux store in each test case so that the state will not be shared between multiple test cases.

E.g.

`Counter.tsx`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { decrement, increment, incrementByAmount, incrementIfOdd, selectCount } from './counterSlice';

export function Counter() {
  const count = useSelector(selectCount);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [incrementAmount, setIncrementAmount] = useState('2');

  const incrementValue = Number(incrementAmount) || 0;

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button aria-label="Decrement value" onClick={() => dispatch(decrement())}>
          -
        </button>
        <span>{count}</span>
        <button aria-label="Increment value" onClick={() => dispatch(increment())}>
          +
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input
          aria-label="Set increment amount"
          value={incrementAmount}
          onChange={(e) => setIncrementAmount(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button onClick={() => dispatch(incrementByAmount(incrementValue))}>Add Amount</button>
        <button onClick={() => dispatch(incrementIfOdd(incrementValue))}>Add If Odd</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`counterSlice.ts`:

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export interface CounterState {
  value: number;
  status: 'idle' | 'loading' | 'failed';
}

const initialState: CounterState = {
  value: 5,
  status: 'idle',
};
export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => {
      state.value += 1;
    },
    decrement: (state) => {
      state.value -= 1;
    },
    incrementByAmount: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.value += action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } = counterSlice.actions;

export const selectCount = (state) => state.counter.value;

export const incrementIfOdd = (amount: number) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const currentValue = selectCount(getState());
  if (currentValue % 2 === 1) {
    dispatch(incrementByAmount(amount));
  }
};

export default counterSlice.reducer;
```

`Counter.test.tsx`:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Counter } from './Counter';
import counterSliceReducer from './counterSlice';

describe('75516577', () => {
  test('should increment the count', () => {
    const store = configureStore({
      reducer: {
        counter: counterSliceReducer,
      },
    });
    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Counter />
      </Provider>
    );
    const incrementBtn = screen.getByLabelText('Increment value');

    fireEvent.click(incrementBtn);
    expect(store.getState().counter.value).toBe(6);
  });
  test('should decrement the count', () => {
    const store = configureStore({
      reducer: {
        counter: counterSliceReducer,
      },
    });
    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Counter />
      </Provider>
    );
    const decrementBtn = screen.getByLabelText('Decrement value');

    fireEvent.click(decrementBtn);
    expect(store.getState().counter.value).toBe(4);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/75516577/Counter.test.tsx (11.959 s)
  75516577
    ✓ should increment the count (49 ms)
    ✓ should decrement the count (7 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.755 s
```